# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUser')

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My Code

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('remove')
        .setDescription('Removes a user to the ticket')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('Remove taged User')
                .addUserOption(option => option.setName('user').setDescription('The user'))), 
    async execute(interaction, client) {

        const channel = interaction.channel;
        const user = interaction.subcommand.getUser('user');
        
        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(user, { 
            'ViewChannel': false,
             'SendMessages': false
        });
        await interaction.channel.reply({ content: `${user} Has been removed from the ticket!`});
    },
};
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUser')

Trying to remove a user from the channel when this command is ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interaction.subcommand` does not exist. You probably meant to use [`interaction.options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ChatInputCommandInteraction?scrollTo=options), which is a [`CommandInteractionOptionResolver`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver)

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('user')
```

The [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html#parsing-options) explains how to parse options from a command.